# ubuntu 20.04LTS started to display an alert that I can click on instead of file dialog, how to re-enable displaying file requesters on screen?

Tags: window, dialog

My desktop is running ubuntu 20.04LTS
It recently mysteriously started to popup a little alert window at the top informing me that a dialog is ready instead of just popping up the dialog. If I don't click in time, the dialog is somewhere in back. I suspect it's some look and feel parameter that accidentally got set, allowing requesters to pop up in the back so they are not seen, and it's highly annoying.

I know it happens in vscode. I believe it happens in many programs, so I think it's system-wide, not just the editor.